# How to run the ChromePlus browser in Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, tar

I'm new to Linux Ubuntu. I was using ChromePlus in Windows 7, it also has a Linux version. So I downloaded it. It's a `chromeplus*.tar.gz` file. I use the command `tar xvzf chromeplus*.tar.gz` to unzip the file and got a bunch of files. I really have no idea about how to run the chrome browser. Is it installed already or I need more steps? There's no `./configure` and `read-me` file.

Comment: can u post a link to there site? I think the name changed to `coolnovo` and it offers deb package to install. http://coolnovo.com/download.html?hl=en is it the same software

Comment: Chromeplus (Coolnovo) hasn't been updated since April 2010 though, so Chromium might be better and more secure.

Comment: You'd be better off installing Chromium, unless you have a specific reason for using ChromePlus..

Comment: Yes, it's Coolnovo. I'd like to use the IE mode as a lot of special reasons. Here's a list of the files in the zip file:

Comment: chrome                                        locales
chrome.pak                                    product_logo_48.png
release_notes
chromeplus_update_bin                         resources
chrome-wrapper                                xdg-settings
libffmpegsumo.so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see, what you have downloaded is a compressed precompiled binary. You can start it by going to the folder where you have extracted it and double-clicking on chrome or typing `./chrome` if you are in terminal. However, on my system it complains about a missing library file:

```
./chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libplc4.so.0d: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have managed to fix this error by copying three of these files from /usr/lib/firefox (without the .0d) extension and to /usr/lib with the added .0d extension. This is the list of files that I had to copy:

```
libnspr4.so
libplc4.so
libplds4.so
```

IMHO, I agree with SirCarlo's comment, you'd probably be better off with Chromium, the font rendering in this program feels weird on my system.